# Twitter_bot Error using python and VS Code

Tags: python, error-handling, twitter

**What should I do?**

I get the following Error:

```
raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.twitter.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:
/2/tweets (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000000D30D34C920>, 'Connection to api.twitter.com timed out. (connect timeout=None)'))
```

I wrote the following Python program in VS Code:

```py
import tweepy

# Authenticate to Twitter
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("CONSUMER_KEY", "CONSUMER_SECRET")
auth.set_access_token("ACCESS_TOKEN", "ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET")

# Create API object
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Create a tweet
api.update_status("Hello Tweepy")
```